# How to Disable List Views In Fragments While Swiping with ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I am Using Normal View-Pager, Which Consists of Multiple Fragments, Until here every thing works fine for me. I will explain in steps,

a)View-Pager Consists of Multiple Fragments, Each Fragments consists of List view.
b)While Swiping, View_pager Swipes Smoothly. But here is my Problem.

When User Tries to Swipe the View pager, List view OnitemClickListner(or)OnTouchListner is getting Overriden, Taking time to Swipe

How can i overcome through this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying Swiping then do this:

```
ListView.setEnabled(false);
```

and when you want it to enable

```
ListView.setEnabled(true);
```

Hope so this will work